# User cannot execute select error 1142

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

My phpmyadmin or MySQL commandline will not let me execute the following query:

```
SELECT customer.First, customer.Last, login.Username, login.Password, customer.Addrln1,
    customer.Addrln2, customer.Postcode, customer.County, customer.Country, customer.Phone, customer.Email, 
    employee.EmpFirst, employee.EmpEmail, move.MoveID, move.CityOrig, move.CityDest, move.CountryOrig, 
    move.CountryDest, move.EnquiryDate, move.Surveydate, move.QuoteDate, move.DepEst, move.DepAct, move.ArrEst, move.ArrAct,
    move.ClearEst, move.ClearAct, move.DelEst, move.DelAct, move.Port, move.Method, move.Status
FROM customer
LEFT JOIN oim2.login ON customer.CustID = login.CustID
LEFT JOIN oim2.move ON customer.CustID = move.CustID
LEFT JOIN oim2.employee ON move.EmpID = employee.EmpID
WHERE customer.First =  'dave' and customer.Last='smith'
```

## 1142 - SELECT command denied to user 'oceanai3'@'localhost' for table 'login'

Dave smith is just an example first and last name, the user can perform the following queries:
        SELECT * from login
        SELECT * FROM move
        SELECT * FROM customer

If I remove the references to login out of the original query I then get the error #1142 - SELECT command denied to user 'oceanai3'@'localhost' for table 'move'. I have pastebin'd the full sql file of the db and it can be found here at: http://pastebin.com/H6aTS74m
I have trawled through a lot of other peoples posts to find an answer but I couldnt find anything that helped me.

Thanks

C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
GRANT SELECT ON database.* TO user@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Replace the placeholders with your values.

Comment: #1044 - Access denied for user 'oceanai3'@'localhost' to database 'oceanai3_oim', the DB is on a shared server provided by justhost, oceanai3 is the root users for my account... I can execute a select statement on this db from all account, but that query will siomply NOT run!

Comment: Well it can't be the root user. Because that would have all permissions. You will have to get the root user to run this command for your user.

Answer (score 0):

I think that, perhaps Jivings' posting of:

```
GRANT SELECT ON database.* TO user@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

*may* require single quotes around user, as:

```
GRANT SELECT ON database.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

least, that worked for me, but I'm using phpMyAdmin 3.5.2.2. Nonetheless, if this can help someone, that's all that matters : )